# How to minimize total distance for deliveries?

Tags: dynamic-programming

There are n houses on an infinitely long road where baskets are to be delivered. Imagine the road as an x-axis starting from negative infinity to positive infinity. We have to select a position of new warehouse in the road so that we can minimize the total distance for deliveries.
there is a single Truck that carry a maximum of m baskets.

task is to find the position for warehouse so that total distance needed to deliver all basket will be minimum possible.

Can anyone help me with question please?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318884396_The_Warehouse_Location_Problem_in_the_Context_of_Vehicle_Routing_Problem_in_the_Production_Companies

Comment: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1369370/FULLTEXT01.pdf